# List displayed as 2 columns

Tags: asp.net, list, multiple-columns

I have a dynamic List (asp .net collection) of Data that I need to display on a aspx page. I want the data in two columns filling up from left to right depending on the number of items on the list. WHat webcontrol would be the best to use in this case?

Comment: Can I also set the column lenght to be 3 so that any more than 3 it spills over to the next column?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx), [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) or [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx). It's really a matter of which features do you need to support (sorting,filtering, paging, etc.) besides your layout requirements (all of the above can do what you need).

GridView and Repeater are a bit heavier but provide easy hooks for implementing more advanced features.

**UPDATE**

Example:

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" id="dltest" 
                Border="1"
                Font-Name="Verdana" CellPadding="4"
                Font-Size="10pt"
                RepeatColumns="2" >
   <ItemTemplate>
     <table>
         <tr>
           <td>
              <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description") %>
           </td>
           <td>
              <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value") %>
           </td>
          </tr>
     </table>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Note: Modified to your needs but this should get you started.

Comment: What property of DataList should I be setting to make it two columns? Can you point me to an example?

Comment: NO I guess I wasnt clear with my question , so what I want is when I have a list of say 5 items .... I need the content of the list to be displayed in 2 columns say 3 on the left and 2 on the right column. when the list length is 3 it should display 2 on the right column and 1 on the left .... the lenght being dynamic I dont know how to specify 2 columns so that the data adjusts itself in two column ... I appreciate your comments they were very helpful

Comment: @user1183713 That's what the `RepeatColumns` setting is for on the DataList. See the markup I posted. The fact that the ItemTemplate is also divided in 2 columns is mere coincidence.

Comment: Thank you @lcarus! This works perfect.Another followup question is what if I have a static list which means I have <table> <bunch of <tr><\tr>....<tr></tr>> </table> now I want the rows to be arranged in 2 columns.Filling up a row at a time.Like 1,2 \n 3,4 \n  Is there a way to achieve this?The catch is I am setting Visible= false for a few of these items in the list dynamically.so the list will have to adjust itself.... since <table> doesnt have the RepeatColumns="2" ... how do you suggest I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

A repeater would work in this situation and allow you alot of flexibility to style it.

CSS

```
.container{margin:0; width:300px;}
.item{float:left;width:150px;height:30px;}
.clear{clear:both;width:100%; height:1px;}
```

ASPX

```
<div class="container">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptTest" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="item"><%#Eval("DataColumn") %></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Eval("DataColumn") would represent the name of the table column you wanted to display, and you can set the datasource for the repeater either in the codebehind or using one of the drag and drop datasource controls.

The CSS will make the data appear as 2 columns going left to right thanks to the "float:left". The container is 300px wide, and the items are going to be 150px each which should give it the two column appearance.

Comment: Did you mean two div tags as shown below? One with float:left and other wihout?
<div class="container"> 
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptTest" runat="server"> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <div><%#Eval("DataColumn") %></div> 
        <div class="item"><%#Eval("DataColumn") %></div>
    </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:Repeater> 
    <div class="clear"></div> 
</div>

Comment: Also how to I control it to be of height say 3 ... so if there are 3 or less items in the list its one column and if its more than 3 it spills over to the second ?

Comment: You would use CSS to adjust how man appear in a row. If you wanted 3  you would adjust the container to be as wide as 3 of the items. So if your items are 150px wide, you would need to make your container 450px wide. You would then be able to fit 3 in a row.

Comment: AH! Now I get it but when I meant 3 I meant the height not the number of columns ... BUt I got my answer thank yo so much! that was very kind of you

Comment: Great! be sure to mark your answer to help people in the future.

Comment: if you give the container `overflow:auto`, you dont need the `<div class="clear"></div>` which, in the end, is a bit messy.

Comment: thanks! wasn't aware of that overflow:auto thing, this will help clean up some front end code for us.