# How to split one column data into two or more columns data in drop down list in asp?

Tags: asp.net, sql, drop-down-menu

I have a table in sql database whose column named 'sub_name' has been successfully included in the asp GridView.

*No need for correcting mistakes in this code. It just for demonstration.*

```
    <asp:Gridview runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <columns>
    <asp:templatefield>
    <asp:Label runat="server" text='<%# bind("sub_name") %>'>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </columns>
    </asp:Gridview>
```

The GridView shows the similar output:

```
subjectname1
subjectname2
subjectname3
subjectname4
subjectname5
subjectname6
subjectname7
subjectname8
subjectname9
subjectname10
```

So how can I manipulate the C# or aspx file to get the same output in GridView **but in two different columns?** Something similar to this:

```
subjectname1  subjectname6
subjectname2  subjectname7
subjectname3  subjectname8
subjectname4  subjectname9
subjectname5  subjectname10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Repeater. [Check this out](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aribeiro/archive/2005/01/12/351439.aspx)

Another answered question like yours [List displayed as 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103314/list-displayed-as-2-columns)